# Prevent KO binding handler from firing on page load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a binding handler that fade elements in and out. Currently, the binding handler triggers on page load, causing all elements using the binding handler to flash concurrently.

I want the element to ignore the binding handler on first pass, and only trigger on subsequent changes to the observables. It is not viable to add a flag to the observables, since they are replaced when new data arrives from the server.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.highlight = {
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor(), vm = viewModel;
    {
        var iterations = 3;
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            $(element).fadeTo("fast", 0.03);
            $(element).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        }
    }        
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make it trigger on a value of `true` and other values not?

Comment: Where should this value be located? At the VM root or inside the object constructors? Because I replace the entire object on new data, the value will always be set to true.

Comment: @mupersan82 i would make it a part of your vm- i wouldn't rebuild your vm everytime...